# Keeping track of position after sorting

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to apply xsl to the result set returned by Analysis Service database.
The result set looks like the following...

```
<Axis name="Axis1">
  <Tuples>
    <Tuple>
      <Member Hierarchy="[Org].[Class1]">
        <UName>[Org].[Class1].&amp;[10629]</UName>
        <Caption>Independent</Caption>
        <LName>[Org].[Class1].[Ownership]</LName>
        <LNum>2</LNum>
        <DisplayInfo>65898</DisplayInfo>
        <PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME>[Org].[Class1].&amp;[2]</PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME>
      </Member>
    </Tuple>
    <Tuple>
      <Member Hierarchy="[Org].[Class1]">
        <UName>[Org].[Class1].&amp;[14331]</UName>
        <Caption>A #5839</Caption>
        <LName>[Org].[Class1].[Owner Region]</LName>
        <LNum>3</LNum>
        <DisplayInfo>65537</DisplayInfo>
        <PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME>[Org].[Class1].&amp;[10629]</PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME>
      </Member>
    </Tuple>
    ....
  </Tuples>
</Axis>

<CellData>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="0">
    <FmtValue>Ownership</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="1">
    <ForeColor>0</ForeColor>
    <FmtValue>73%</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="2">
    <ForeColor>0</ForeColor>
    <FmtValue>68%</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="3">
    <ForeColor>0</ForeColor>
    <FmtValue>70%</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="4">
    <ForeColor>0</ForeColor>
    <FmtValue>59%</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="5">
    <FmtValue>Owner Region</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  <Cell CellOrdinal="6">
    <ForeColor>0</ForeColor>
    <FmtValue>75%</FmtValue>
  </Cell>
  .....
</CellData>
```

Each Tuple above has a corresponding set of Cells in the CellData.
So, if the file is parsed sequentially, the relevant cells can be gathered using the `position()` of the Tuple.

However, if the Tuple is sorted using xsl-sort, LNum property, and iterated over using for-each, the position of the Tuples is now changed and so can not find the corresponding Cell for the Tuple.

How can I keep track of the Tuple ordinal based on UName, so that I can get to the relevant cell.
I have created a key for the UName as

```
<xsl:key name="tuples-by-uName" match="/xa:root/xa:Axes/xa:Axis/xa:Tuples/xa:Tuple" use="xa:Member/xa:UName" />
<xsl:key name="tuples-by-parentUName" match="/xa:root/xa:Axes/xa:Axis/xa:Tuples/xa:Tuple" use="xa:Member/xa:PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME" />
```

And want to iterate over the tuples using something like the following.

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('tuples-by-parentUName', $thisQuestion/xa:Member/xa:UName)">
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="xa:Member/xa:LNum" order="descending"/>
```

Here I need the original position of the Tuple so I can calculate the position of the Cell.

Have spent a lot of time, but can not figure this one out.

Comment: Why `tuples-byparentUName` is "queried" with `UName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:variable name="originalPosition" select="count(preceding::xa:Tuple) + 1"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="originalPosition">
    <xsl:number count="xa:Tuple" level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
```